# Parameter to panHandlers to handle multiple PanResponder?

Tags: react-native

Let say I have two simple animated view. I want to know which `View` is getting panned. How do I pass any parameter to it or any other way to detect?  Thanks

```
<Animated.View {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}></Animated.View>
<Animated.View {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}></Animated.View>
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this ?

Comment: @AidanDoherty  Nope.

Comment: Hmm only solution i can think of is creating two different pan responders maybe like Button1Responder and Button2Responder that can do different things onGrant.

Answer (score 1):

```
//passing parameters
<Animated.View {...this._PanResponder('pass parameter here 1').panHandlers}></Animated.View>
<Animated.View {...this._PanResponder('pass parameter here 2').panHandlers}></Animated.View>
//handler
panResponder = (receive parameter here) =>
PanResponder.create({ 
//code here
.
.
.
})
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Code only answers are usually not very useful unless they explain what they do. This is very true of long segments of code. Please consider adding an explanation of what you changed or wrote.

Answer (score 0):

In your `PanResponder` implementation check the `target` property and use `findNodeHandle` to figure out which component it references e.g.

```
import { findNodeHandle } from 'react-native'

...

constructor (props) {
  super (props)

  // initialize array for refs
  this.animatedViewRefs = []

  this.panResponder = PanResponder.create({
    ...
    onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: ({ nativeEvent: { target } }, _) => {  
      const component = this.findComponentByTarget(target)

      // now `component` will either be null or a reference to your animated view
    }
    ...
  })
}

// helper method for finding component
findComponentByTarget (target) {
  for (const ref of this.animatedViewRefs) {
    if (target === findNodeHandle(ref)) {
      return ref
    }
  }

  return null
}
```

In your render method you will have

```
<Animated.View 
  ref={ref => (this.animatedViewRefs[0] = ref)} 
  {...this.panResponder.panHandlers} />

<Animated.View 
  ref={ref => (this.animatedViewRefs[1] = ref)} 
  {...this.panResponder.panHandlers} />

...

<Animated.View 
  ref={ref => (this.animatedViewRefs[n] = ref)} 
  {...this.panResponder.panHandlers} />
```

Answer (score -1):

I have not tested this but i think you should be able to create different responders for each view similar to the example below.

```
this._firstPanResponder = PanResponder.create({
  onPanResponderGrant: (evt, gestureState) => {
    // Do something when the first responder is granted
    this.doFirst();
  },
});
this._secondPanResponder = PanResponder.create({
  onPanResponderGrant: (evt, gestureState) => {
    // Do something when the second responder is granted
    this.doSecond();
  },
});
```

Then the view should work look like this.

```
<Animated.View {...this._firstPanResponder.panHandlers}></Animated.View>
<Animated.View {...this._secondPanResponder.panHandlers}></Animated.View>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: So if 50 animated view , 50 different pan responder ?

Comment: Would it be much different from using 50 Touchable components pretty sure they just use panResponder aswell. I could be wrong though.

Comment: It also depends on what you want the different views to do. In my case i just want to tell what component has been touched and reuse  onPanResponderMove function.

Comment: Last time I was working, I was trying to make a simple game. Many square on screen where you can drag them around to sort them in certain order. :P

Comment: I don't know if panResponder would be best for that maybe some kind of 2D interactive game engine. Details like that in the original question would have been useful. :)

Comment: Although I just tried to implement this method and i cant seem to have multiple responders granted at one time :/. Similar to when you cant touch two button components at the same time.